# Separate Read-Host concatenated string, then add XML tags

Tags: xml, loops, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell code in which I'm trying to separate a concatenated string from the two `Read-Hosts` inputs:

```psh
$Response = 'Y'
$URLName = $Null
$SecondURLName = @()

# Enter URL
do {
    $URLName = Read-Host "Please enter the URL (Example:  www.example.com)" 
    $Response = Read-Host 'Do you want to add more URLs? (y/n)'
    $SecondURLName += $URLName
} until ($Response -eq 'n')
```

What would be the best method to have the concatenated string separated with the same added XML tag below:

```psh
# Create a new XML File with member root node
$XMLDocument = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument

# New Node
$MemberRoot = $XMLDocument.CreateElement("url")

# Append as child to an existing node
$XMLDocument.appendChild($MemberRoot)

# Add URL to member Node
$XMLEntry = $MemberRoot.appendChild($XMLDocument.CreateTextNode("$SecondURLName"))

# Save File 
$XMLDocument.Save("urls.xml")
```

Here's the current results I have with the script saved in `urls.xml` file:

```xml
<url>thisisfromread-host1.com thisisfromread-host2.com</url>
```

What I need saved in the urls.xml file is only:

```xml
<url>thisisfromread-host1.com</url>
<url>thisisfromread-host2.com</url>
```

There has to be a simple thing out there that I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$SecondURLName` is defined as an array, so you need to process it in a loop. Putting the variable in a string (`"$SecondURLName"`) merges the array elements into a single string, so you end up with a single element. For appending multiple elements you need to add a root element first, though, because XML documents can't have multiple root elements.

```
$xml = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument

$root = $xml.CreateElement('root')
$xml.AppendChild($root) | Out-Null

foreach ($url in $SecondURLName) {
  $newNode = $xml.CreateElement('url')
  $txt = $xml.CreateTextNode($url)
  $newNode.AppendChild($txt) | Out-Null
  $root.AppendChild($newNode) | Out-Null
}

$xml.Save('urls.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, this is getting me to a good path.  So the root element is required in order to implment multiple elements.  Is there anyway to remove root, so that only the child is left on the document?

Comment: XML documents *must* have a *single* root element. Period.